# Linking 20 servers that are located around the world at different datacenters of which I normally connect to individually via SSH

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

How would I link my 20 servers to one "console" or "portal" (website or VPN or what?) so I could manage them there or at least view them and see they are online etc.  The OS's vary from FreeBSD to a couple linux variants (Debian, CentOS, Ubuntu.) I just need one portal to access them all or at the least view their vitals.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for system management or monitoring software.  Popular open source products are,

- nagios
- munin
- cacti
- zabbix

Here's a nice [list at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems).

None of them are trivial to setup, but they do vary in their complexity.  In the above list, I would rate them (in order of setup complexity, highest first), nagios, zabbix, cacti, munin.

I've never used it, but [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) is a product which can automate system management (installing stuff, configuring stuff, etc.) and can handle multiple machines.

Comment: For monitoring those are a great choice!

Comment: There are more choices for configuration management: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software

That said, puppet is my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [ClusterSSH](http://clusterssh.sourceforge.net/) is what you are looking for.

Setup a .csshrc file, containing something like

```
allmachines = root@host1.domain.com root@host2.domain.com root@host1.domain2.com root@host2.domain2.com
```

You could then connect to all of them at once using

```
cssh allmachines
```

which will open a terminal for every machine and give you ONE input window which will send your commands to ALL terminals. Type `top[RETURN]` once and it starts on all 30 machines.

Want groups? All european servers? All Mailservers? Set them up in the .csshrc file and you have them...